# Understanding the strdup function

Tags: c, pointers

I tried to build my own strdup function, as I understand the  function is supposed to work as strcpy but with a string that can be used in another function, but in my prototype I dont understand why my chars are not copied.

I have made this prototype, but I dont understand why the pointer that my function return doesn't display my string

```
char            *my_strdup(char *str)
{
  char          *new_str;
  char          *to_copy;
  int           i;

  to_copy = str;
  i = strlen(str + 1);
  new_str = malloc(sizeof(*new_str) * i + 1);
  while(i - 1 > 0)
    {
      *new_str = *to_copy;
      new_str++;
      to_copy++;
      i--;
    }
  return(new_str);
}
```

and here is my test function:

```
int             main()
{
  char          *str;

  str = my_strdup("helloo");
  printf("%s\n", str);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are returning a pointer to the end of the string, and not the beginning of the string.

You need to return the pointer that `malloc` gave you. That's what you placed in `new_str` in your initial assignment to `new_str`. But instead of returning that, you modify that pointer and then return it.

There are a lot of other problems with your code. For example at this point:

```
i = strlen(str + 1);
```

You calculate the length of the string that starts at `str[1]`. That will lead to undefined behaviour if your string is of length zero.

Perhaps you meant to write:

```
i = strlen(str) + 1;
```

In which case your call to `malloc` would be allocating too much.

Using `sizeof(*new_str)` is pointless since that is guaranteed to equal `1`.

Anyway, rather than trying to remedy your code, here are some possible alternatives.

```
char *mystrdup(const char *str)
{
    char *result = malloc(strlen(str) + 1);
    char *psrc = str;
    char *pdst = result;
    while (*psrc != 0)
    {
        *pdst = *psrc;
        pdst++;
        psrc++;
    }
    *pdst = '\0';
    return result;
}
```

You could make the body of the loop more concise like this:

```
*pdst++ = *psrc++;
```

You could do it with a for loop:

```
char *mystrdup(const char *str)
{
    size_t len = strlen(str);
    char *result = malloc(len + 1);
    for (size_t i = 0; i <= len; i++)
        result[i] = str[i];
    return result;
}
```

Or you could even using `memcpy` like this:

```
char *mystrdup(const char *str)
{
    size_t len = strlen(str);
    char *result = malloc(len + 1);
    memcpy(result, str, len + 1);
    return result;
}
```

Note that in all cases the value that I get back from `malloc` is returned unmodified.

I've ignored the possible error condition on the calls to malloc. You can worry about that!

Comment: I have to go back to the begining with a new_str-- ?

Comment: Well, it's much cleaner to introduce two pointer variables. One pointing to the string, and one pointing at the character to be assigned to. Or use array indexing. My answer now has three distinct approaches. But in none of them do I ever modify the variable in which I stored the string pointer returned by `malloc`. Doing so leads to pain.